# Price per hour or per month

Tags: vps, cloud, pricing

I am trying to select a host for my Node.js applications. They are low-traffic applications - I expect an average of 1-2 hours of use per day, so I am looking for a package where I can pay per use only. But I am confused by the different pricing schemes of price per month vs. price per hour - I am not sure which price takes effect when.

For example, DigitalOcean FAQ says that: *"If you use your server for less than 672 hours during the month, you will be billed for each hour that you used it. If you use your server for more than 672 hours that month, you will be billed at the monthly cost".  But on the other hand, in the next question they say: "Am I charged while my Droplet is in a powered-off state? - Yes. Your diskspace, CPU, RAM, and IP address are all reserved while your Droplet is powered off"*.     If I understand this correctly, this means that, even when no one enters my website, they charge me as if I do use the site.

As another example, AtlanticNet says that: *"With per-second billing, you only pay for what you use" ... "Monthly pricing based on average use."*. If I understand this correctly, this means that the only effective price is price per hour, and I pay only per actual use.

So, my question is: if my Node.js application is always on and waiting for users, but users use it only 1 hour per day, how much will I pay? Will I pay for an entire month, or only for 30 hours?

Comment: Please note that we do not allow questions that are related in a way that is seeking advice for selecting a service such as hosting. If you need help deciding on choosing a host then please use our chat channel or alternatively ask directly from the service provider (Most have online chat that will answer promptly any sale related questions).

Comment: @bybe, I did not ask for an advice for selecting a host, I asked for an explanation of how the pricing is calculated. I don't think this is answered in the catch-all post you marked as duplicate.